# ASP.NET - save pdf file on server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a aspx page which returns a pdf file with this code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Order-" & Request("OrderNo") & ".pdf")
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(pdfContent)
HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
```

What modifications needs to be done to the code so the file is saved to the hard drive on the server? I guess BinaryWrite has to be replaced with something else, but what?

I'm very grateful for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just specify the Path and the pdfcontent as parameters to the `File.WriteAllBytes` method as so:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/SubdirectoryInCurrentWebApp"),pdfContent);
```

You generally can't save any content outside your local application directory unless you configure the Application pool your application runs under with a user that has enough privileges to write to the destination directory. But out of the box, you should be able to write to subdirectories inside your web application.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works great! I just had to add the file name to your code above.

Answer (score 2):

You can write binary data to disk by calling `File.WriteAllBytes`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to dump the bytes from `pdfContent` to a file, then `IO.File.WriteAllBytes("{A path}",pdfContent)` should do it.